# Running batch file with arguments from C#

Tags: c#, batch-file, arguments, xcopy

I have a batch file like this

```
@echo off
xcopy /e %1 %2
```

I have my C# code as follows:

```
string MyBatchFile = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\MybatchFile.bat";
string _sourcePath = @"C:\FolderToCopy";
string _tempTargetPath = @"C:\TargetFolder\";

var process = new Process { 
                   StartInfo = { 
                      Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}",
                                                _sourcePath,
                                                _tempTargetPath) 
                                } 
                          };
process.StartInfo.FileName = MyBatchFile;
bool b = process.Start();
```

I expect this to copy the source files to target location. But nothing happens. My console window also does not stay for enough time so that I can see the error. Can anyone guide to achieve this. I am new in batch files processing.

**Edit**

By adding a `pause` in the end of batch file. Able to reproduce error. Getting error as

```
Files not found - Program
```

Running batch file directly does work fine. Just now noticed......when source path has any spaces....I am getting error

Comment: `bat` files are scripts processed with `cmd.exe`. Simply try to run `cmd.exe` with `/C` key.

Comment: You can add a `pause` command to the end of the batch file and then it will wait for you to press a key before exiting

Comment: I need to run it through C# application. You mean to say....`process.StartInfo.FileName = @"cmd.exe /c " + MyBatchFile` ??

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv `Process` uses default programs if the filename is a file and not a program.

Comment: @rapsalands I guess so, because it's hard to believe that a batch file can be considered as a standalone process. Please also see Default's comment if I'm wrong.

Comment: edited my post with source path changed.

Comment: @rapsalands use `string MyBatchFile = @"\"C:\Program Files (x86)\MybatchFile.bat\"";` (note the **\"** around the whole expression)

Comment: @Default: Getting compilation error.

Comment: change file path to `string MyBatchFile = @"C:\Program~1\MybatchFile.bat"`

Comment: @rapsalands could you be more specific? what does the compilation error say?

Comment: sorry......it showing me syntax error

Comment: @rapsalands that is just as little information as "compilation error". But I saw it myself. since there's a `@` before the string, you should use `string MyBatchFile = @"""C:\Program Files (x86)\MybatchFile.bat""";`. Next time, as a suggestion, a little more details would help.

Comment: @Default: Will surely keep in mind. Thanks and sorry for being a bit lazy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What about quoting argument?

```
Arguments = String.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\"", _sourcePath, _tempTargetPath) …
```

Answer (score 6):

.bat file is a text file, in order to execute it, you should start cmd process.
Start it like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c yourbatch.bat");
```

Additional arguments may follow. Try this without c#, in a cmd window, or Run dialog.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
string MyBatchFile = @"C:\MybatchFile.bat";
string _sourcePath = @"C:\FolderToCopy\*.*";
string _tempTargetPath = @"C:\TargetFolder\";
```

i.e. add `*.*` to the source path

and add a 3rd line `pause` to the batch file

```
@echo off
copy /e %1 %2
pause
```

Comment: thanks.....getting error as `Files not found - Program`. Edited my post with sourcepath changed.

Comment: That may be due to the paths - are there any files in the source folder (and you do need `*.*` for the xcopy command) - I have it running here.

Comment: I have files in Source path. Running batch file directly does work fine. Just now noticed......when source path has any spaces....I am getting error

Comment: paths with spaces will need to be wrapped in "'s or use the DOS 8 character path.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that using this approach or calling `cmd.exe` is problematic with long argument lists. For those cases, I have found that using `powershell.exe` instead of `cmd.exe` to work well:

```
string MyBatchFile = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\MybatchFile.bat";
string _sourcePath = @"C:\FolderToCopy";
string _tempTargetPath = @"C:\TargetFolder\";

var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo = {
        Arguments = string.Format("\"& '{0}' '{1}' '{2}'\"",
            MyBatchFile,
            _sourcePath,
            _tempTargetPath)
        }
};
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
bool b = process.Start();
```

Note that the entire arguments list needs to be wrapped in quotes and the batch file path is preceeded by an `&`.